# Getting error 91 "Object variable or with block variable not set"

Tags: excel, vba, xpath

Running the below code throws error 91. What is wrong with it?

```vb
Sub abc()
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    Dim elem As HTMLBaseElement
    objIE.Visible = True

    objIE.navigate "https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuote.jsp?symbol=COALINDIA"
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    Set elem = getXPathElement("/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/ul[1]/li[1]/span[1]", objIE.document)
    Range("A5").Value = elem.innerText

End Sub
```

Public Function getXPathElement(sXPath As String, objElement As HTMLBaseElement) As HTMLBaseElement
    Dim sXPathArray() As String

```
Dim sNodeName As String
Dim sNodeNameIndex As String
Dim sRestOfXPath As String
Dim lNodeIndex As Long
Dim lCount As Long

' Split the xpath statement
sXPathArray = Split(sXPath, "/")
sNodeNameIndex = sXPathArray(1)
If Not InStr(sNodeNameIndex, "[") > 0 Then
    sNodeName = sNodeNameIndex
    lNodeIndex = 1
Else
    sXPathArray = Split(sNodeNameIndex, "[")
    sNodeName = sXPathArray(0)
    lNodeIndex = CLng(Left(sXPathArray(1), Len(sXPathArray(1)) - 1))
End If
sRestOfXPath = Right(sXPath, Len(sXPath) - (Len(sNodeNameIndex) + 1))

Set getXPathElement = Nothing
For lCount = 0 To objElement.ChildNodes().Length - 1
    If UCase(objElement.ChildNodes().Item(lCount).nodeName) = UCase(sNodeName) Then
        If lNodeIndex = 1 Then
            If sRestOfXPath = "" Then
                Set getXPathElement = objElement.ChildNodes().Item(lCount)
            Else
                Set getXPathElement = getXPathElement(sRestOfXPath, objElement.ChildNodes().Item(lCount))
            End If
        End If
        lNodeIndex = lNodeIndex - 1
    End If
Next lCount
```

End Function

Comment: The debugger will tell you for sure, but I'm going to bet that `Set elem = getXPathElement` failed, which means trying to read `elem.innerText` is causing the error.

Comment: You're making a member call against an object reference that's `Nothing`. What line is throwing the error? What's `getXPathElement` doing exactly?

Answer (score 1):

That element has an id you can use instead

```vb
Option Explicit
Public Sub abc()
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer, elem As HTMLBaseElement
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    objIE.Visible = True

    objIE.navigate "https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuote.jsp?symbol=COALINDIA"
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    Set elem = objIE.document.getElementById("lastPrice")
    Debug.Print elem.innerText
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A5").Value = elem.innerText
    objIE.Quit
End Sub
```

I am guessing `getXPathElement` is a custom function? There isn't a native XPath selector method. If so, include the function in your question if you must have a solution using that function.